# SQL select query comparing multiple rows against 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am trying to write a SQL select query to solve the following problem. I have a list of customers with accounts showing an account open date and an account closed date. I need to ascertain whether the customer is eligible to vote based on whether they have had continuous membership upto 30th September 2014 (i.e. have an account open). Continuous membership would count if they closed an account on the same day as opening a new account. My initial table is as follows:

```
CUS_ID | ACC_ID | OPEN_DT | CLOSE_DT
1 | 1001 | 01/01/2010 | 01/12/2013
1 | 1002 | 10/03/2014 | 01/11/2014
1 | 1003 | 01/11/2014 | 01/01/2015
1 | 1004 | 01/01/2015 | NULL
2 | 1005 | 01/01/2014 | 10/08/2014
2 | 1006 | 10/08/2014 | 01/02/2015
2 | 1007 | 05/02/2015 | NULL
3 | 1008 | 01/10/2014 | NULL
4 | 1009 | 01/09/2014 | 31/03/2015
```

You can see that customer 1 has had continuous membership since 10/03/2014 and is therefore eligible. 
Customer 2 is ineligible as there was a break in membership and his latest account was opened after 30th September 2014. 
Customer 3 is ineligible as his account was opened after 30th September 2014. Customer 4 is ineligible as the account is closed.

My result should look like this:

```
CUS_ID | ELIGIBLE
1 | Y
2 | N
3 | N
4 | N
```

I have tried joing the table on itself and cmparing open date with closed date but in some cases there are more than 2 records per customer that need to be checked. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For cust 1 there is also break

Answer (score 0):

If the records do not overlap (as is the case with your sample data), you can use a little trick.  Count the number of days since the date you are interested in.  Then sum the number of days in the records for each customer records.  If these are equal, then all days are covered.

It requires a bit of logic to implement this, but here is the idea:

```
select cus_id,
       (case when sum(datediff(day,
                               (case when open_dt < thedate then thedate else open_dt end),
                               (case when close_dt > today or close_dt is null then today else close_dt end)
                              )) =
                  sum(datediff(day, thedate, today))
             then 'y' else 'n'
        end) as eligible
from table t cross join
     (select cast('2014-09-30' as date) as thedate,
             cast(getdate() as date) as today) as params
where close_dt is null or close_dt >= thedate
group by cus_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive CTE is a good choice here.

Here my query but I have made no test and some debug is perhaps needed.

```
    with a as
(
select CUS_ID , OPEN_DT  
from tab as t1 
where CLOSE_DT is null

UNION ALL

select cus_id, open_dt 
    from table1 as t2
        inner join A as A1
            on A1.CUS_ID = T2.Cust_ID AND A1.Open_dt = t2.close_dt
)

Select Cust_id, Eligible case when MIN(open_dt) < '2014-09-30' then 'Y' else 'N' from a group by Cust_id
```